# A spinning pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, rotational-dynamics, string, gyroscopes

I just thought of a scenario :
We **rotate** a sphere that is hanging from a string about vertical axis and then allow it to oscillate like a pendulum . Will its time period differ from a sphere performing pure oscillations?

Please answer my question with a clear justification.

Comment: So you have a spinning sphere that is then also moving side to side in a pendulum motion attached to a string?   And you are comparing it to a non-spinning sphere that is also moving side to side in a pendulum motion attached to a string?

Comment: Are you concerned with the non-ideal behaviors of the string?  Spinning a string will change its length a bit as the string winds up.

Comment: Exactly, You got my point.  Can you please answer it?

Comment: No it is an ideal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spinning will cause the sphere to exhibit [gyroscopic effects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cquvA_IpEsA). Thus the sphere will not always rest at the same angle that the non-spinning one will.  This will have the same effect as shortening the string slightly (because the center of gravity of the ball no longer goes quite so far down at the bottom of the pendulum).  This will make the period shorter.

If you had a massless sphere, or a point source mass, this effect would not occur.